# Java to read a file and add line numbers, how do I not number blank lines?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Okay so I am working on a Java project which reads a file specified by the user and takes the information and adds line numbers. Good for poems, and other types of literature. Now I get the line numbers to work fine, but the problem I am having is that I have to make sure any blank lines are printed, but are not numbered. Any help?

Comment: Not that kind of site, this is more for FAQs and short format questions than for solving programming exercises.

Comment: A well indented code is easier to understand. It will help others to answer your question faster.

Comment: In case you removed the code thinking it caused a negative reaction -- I want to tell you that posting code in a question is common, almost expected, so that is no problem. It is in fact helpful as it shows what you've tried and where improvement can be made

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a few changes:

1. After determining that poemScanner.hasNext() read the next line into a String variable
2. Once you have a String check to see if that string is all whitespace. You could use a regex or some other manual mechanism. I prefer to use something like the isBlank method from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

The psuedo-code would look like this:

```
while(poemScanner.hasNext()){
  String thisLine = poemScanner.nextLine();

  if(StringUtils.isBlank(thisLine)){
     System.out.println(thisLine);
  }
  else {
     System.out.println(lineNumber + thisLine);
  }
}
```

That skips over some of the details but should give you the gist of how to make this work.

Comment: depending on his knowledge, figuring out how to include a third-party dependency may be a bit too much

Comment: When I'm coaching newer devs at work I tend to choose convenient, common libraries like `StringUtils` over regular expressions. Yes there can be a penalty or some hassle adding a library but thats something that they need to learn anyway and ultimately leads to more readable code with less room for error than a regex.  I applied the same strategy here.

Answer (score 0):

Checking if the line is not null will not work to see if it is a blank line.  You can try the following:

```
        if(!isNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) {
            System.out.println(poemScanner.nextLine());
        }


   public boolean isNullOrWhiteSpace(String str)
   {
         if(str == null || str.length() == 0) return true;
         for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
               if (!Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)))
                          return false;
         return true;
   }
```